# How to Write Stand-alone Mathematica Projects/Programs

Tags: programming, deployment

I wish to write several stand-alone projects/programs using Mathematica because of its easy-to-use graphics.  I could use Python for this, but Mathematica has built-in graphics that would be better and much easier to program than Python's limited graphics capability.

For example, as a pilot project, I would like to write a 2-D simulation of Conway's Life using the ClickPane for easy initial data entry.  This can be done in the notebook environment, but I have not been able to discover how one gets an existing program to initialize and run when its notebook is first opened.

I have exhaustively researched the provided Mathematica Documentation and many Mathematica textbooks, but I cannot find a single source that shows one the functions and steps necessary to achieve automatic program start.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not really possible. You still need the runtime, at least the [CDF player](https://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/), which is going to be quite large. Mathematica is not really meant for application development.

Comment: Unfortunately, the free CDF Player is encumbered with so many restrictions that it cannot really be used as a delivery mechanism for standalone programmes. This is a question with which I have wrestled extensively, and for which I have still not found a satisfactory solution. If Wolfram Research would make cloud credits available for purchase to those without fancy service accounts, Mathematica would find much wider usage among independent developers.

Comment: "I need information on how to set up a program to run outside of the Mathematica notebook environment" Are you looking for [scripts](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html)? This would do exactly this. It requires the user to have Mathematica installed, but it doesn't require the notebook environment.

Comment: Not sure exactly what kind of projects/programs you are working on. Why do you requiire "stand-alone" for your application? Mathematica is really designed for interactive development.

Comment: Take a look af everything related to CDF format (not stats), DynamicModule, Manipulate etc. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3964/5478 and related topics. Is this what you need? One needs at least a free cdf player to run them though.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  [How do you configure Mathematica 9 to automatically evaluate all notebooks?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23084/363)

Comment: A method to do this was demonstrated at the 2018 Wolfram Technology Conference in October.  Steven showed the free standalone Wolfram Kernel that is used to create standalone applications.  He also has be demonstrating some of this functionality on his Twitch channel.